# Read a .txt files containing text into panda dataframe with single row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read many .txt files which are text files extracted from pdf articles.
I want to create dataframe of each .txt files where each row will have all the text from the article. However, I am running into this issue that upon reading using pd.read_csv(),
the parser splits into multiple columns. Basically, I am trying to get article dataframe of shape (n,1) where n is number of rows containing text per article.

Below is an example of result I am getting:

```
pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=None, header=None, skip_blank_lines=True, on_bad_lines='warn')
```

[image]

There will be thousands of .txt files to load into the Dataframe, what can be the best way to deal with this.
Thank you

A portion of .txt file:

Text1:

The tissue samples of the shoots (a mix of leaves and stems) and fibrous rootlets were immediately analysed as fresh materials, fixed in the NaH2PO4- Na2HPO4 fixative solution containing 2.5% glutaraldehyde, or frozen in liquid nitrogen and then stored at −80 °C, depending on experimental requirements. The fibrous rootlets fixed in the fixative solution were taken and stained for 30 min in 1% sarranine followed by rinsing with sterilized deionized water. Then, they were stained for 5 min in aniline blue and sequentially rinsed once with 95% ethanol and twice with anhydrous ethanol, and sequentially soaked for 5 min in the solution composed of both anhydrous ethanol and dimethylbenzene as 1(v):1(v) and for 5 min in dimethylbenzene.

Text2:

Although ar- tificial lighting can extend growth duration in controlled environments, such as greenhouses and indoor growth facili- ties, we focus here on field-grown crops, given the limited feasibility with which many staple crops may be grown in controlled environments. The proportion of St used for pho- tosynthesis in plants could potentially increase through in- troduction of different pigments and their associated proteins in plants (see “Opportunities” below). Of the effi- ciency terms, which are genetically determined, ep and ei were largely targeted for improvement during the Green Revolution and are approaching the theoretical limit in most crops (Evans, 1993; Hay, 1995; Sinclair, 1998); therefore, these hold little further potential for improving Yp in major crop species.

Comment: Could you please share the text that you are trying to load in this example?

Comment: Create an empty dataframe and iterate over the TXT files in a for-loop, read each file and append it to the dataframe.

Comment: @Sheldon Looks like I cannot attach a text file here, instead pasted a sample of text which you can write to a .txt file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have tried that, but even before going the for loop, I am stuck on getting a single txt file to be read properly in the dataframe.

Comment: When you pass `delimiter=None`, you tell python to automatically detect the delimiter. Per the docs: "If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool" Instead, you could try passing a nonsense character separator, a symbol that doesn't appear in the text perhaps

Comment: Alternately, does this answer your question? [Python Pandas read\_csv to dataframe without separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192599/python-pandas-read-csv-to-dataframe-without-separator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pathlib
import io
import pandas as pd

DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path('.')

data = []
for filename in DATA_DIR.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        data.append(fp.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Text'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                Text
0  The tissue samples of the shoots (a mix of lea...
1  Although ar- tificial lighting can extend grow...
```

Answer (score 2):

When passing `delimiter=None`, Python's parsing engine tries to automatically detect the separator. So when trying to read the Text1 example that you provided, `read_csv` splits the text using commas (`,`) as the separators:

[image]

A quick and dirty way to circumvent this problem is to specify a crazy delimiter that you will never encounter in your text.
For instance:

`pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter='I_am_a_delimiter', header=None, skip_blank_lines=True)`

This will return:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to create such a dataframe can be

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data = []

# Begin of possible loop to collect file contents in list
p = Path('file.txt')
data.append(p.read_text())
# End of loop

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ['Text'])
```