How to handle cell with comma when using pd.readcsv? Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 88, saw 2
I'm reading a set of .csv files and adding them to one giant data frame called 'df', but I kept getting this error in some of my files: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 88, saw 2
I actually figured out what was likely causing this: the CSVs I'm reading are the result of a newsletter sign up form, and there is a column where people specified what town they lived in. However, some users put a comma in that (ex. "El Paso, Texas" instead of just "El Paso").
Is there a way to handle this within the .read_csv command that doesn't involve just skipping the line? This error came up ~ a dozen times across the maybe 35 spreadsheets I'm stitching together, so I could theoretically alter the spreadsheets manually, but I'm trying to figure out how I could handle this in the future with new spreadsheets.
For reference, here is my code to add the spreadsheets to the dataframe.
for spreadsheet in os.listdir(path):
    file_name = path + '/' + spreadsheet
 
    if file_name[-3:] == "csv":
        try:
            temp = pd.read_csv(path + '/' + spreadsheet, encoding='utf-16')
            df = pd.concat([df, temp])
        except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
            print('Something went wrong with' + file_name + f"error: {e}")
    else: continue 


Is this a file with one field per line? If so, could you ignore commas entirely? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192599/python-pandas-read-csv-to-dataframe-without-separator

A field with comma should be in quotes. If not, it's not a valid CSV. You should fix the code that creates the CSV.

@Barmar couldn't agree with you more but that's out of my hands — these are CSVs generated by Meta with a list of emails from a Facebook ad for a newsletter

Can you try to read the csv file using python csv module instead of pandas read_csv?
Something like this?
import csv
with open('some.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
print(row)

Can you try this and see if it works.
pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-16', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
If still fails, try with a different quoting method
pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-16', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, escapechar='\\')

@XXavier I suspect pandas uses the csv module internally.

If you can have unquoted commas, there's no reliable way to know which commas are field separators and which should be included in the values. Unless there's only one field that can have commas in it, you're screwed.

If there's only one field like this, you can remove all the fields before and after it, then join the remaining fields.
